# Subclassing a non-constructor

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I was trying to teach myself JavaScript classes and I found this thing I don't understand. Can somebody please explain why I'm getting different results when I run those snippets?

```
class Foo extends console { } // TypeError: console is not a constructor
```

This one makes perfect sense: it's an error if you try to extend a function that is not a constructor.

But when I try this with other non-constructors, things are different.

```
class Bar extends Symbol { }  // This works
let bar = new Bar();          // TypeError: Symbol is not a constructor
```

I don't understand the difference: in both cases I'm getting the same error, but sometimes in the class declaration and other times only when I try to create an instance of my subclass.

Comment: console is not a constructor it is a object

Comment: Thats why we call console.log() console.warn(), console.error() etc

Comment: I can't reproduce your `TypeError: Symbol is not a constructor`.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I'm using Chrome

Comment: May be environment matters here. Extending `built-ins` works in real `ES6` environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend (subclass) any *constructor*. *Any* function can act as constructor when is called with `new` operator (and ES6 `class` constructors can't be called without `new`). So an object is created with a `constructor` property.

In your case `console` is *just* an object, and `console.constructor` is `Object`:

```
console.constructor === Object // true
```

and you could extend it:

```
class SuperConsole extends console.constructor {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  // ...
}

const myconsole = new SuperConsole();
typeof myconsole.log === 'function'; // FALSE!
```

but... Object.prototype don't have `log`, `info`, ... methods because they are attached statically to a simple object, and extending it is **useless**.

Btw you can attach more methods to `console` object, or copy them to another object or constructor `prototype`, example:

```
function Superconsole() {
}

Superconsole.prototype = console;

var myconsole = new Superconsole();
myconsole.log('It works');
// It works
```